# Split a column into several rows using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-re

I have a table which I want to split so that there is a new line for every object in part 1 with every id of part 2. The table I have looks this way:

| part 1 | part 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | [{'name': 'xxx', 'id': 234564}, {'name': 'yyyy', 'id': 1357923}] |
| 690 | [{'name': 'fff', 'id': 19204023412}] |

What I would expect is the following:

| part 1 | part 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 234564 |
| 12345 | 1357923 |
| 690 | 19204023412 |

Can you help me on how to implement that in Python?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please a data set for testing

Comment: It's not an easy problem since your column `part 2` is a list on the first row and a dict on the second one. Where the data come from? Is it possible to change the data format upstream?

Comment: How are you getting the data? is it a simple table or an array, object, etc?

Comment: It works to have both in a dictionary format, does it make that easier?

Answer (score 0):

If the values in `part 2` are strings, you can convert them with `ast.literal_eval` to python objects (you can skip this step if they are lists/dictionaries already):

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["part 2"] = df["part 2"].apply(literal_eval)
```

Then you can use `.apply` + `.explode` to obtain your dataframe:

```py
df = df.assign(
    **{
        "part 2": df["part 2"].apply(
            lambda x: [d["id"] for d in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])]
        )
    }
).explode("part 2")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   part 1       part 2
0   12345       234564
0   12345      1357923
1     690  19204023412
```

---

If the values of `part 2` are just list of dictionaries, you can do:

```py
df = df.assign(
    **{"part 2": df["part 2"].apply(lambda x: [d["id"] for d in x])}
).explode("part 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking for a raw python implementation then you can try this:**

```py
def row_splitter(data):
    res_list = []
    for key, val in data.items():
        for item in val:
            id_val = item.get('id')
            key_val_pair = [key, id_val]
            res_list.append(key_val_pair)
    return res_list

data = {12345: [{'name': 'xxx', 'id': 234564}, {'name': 'yyyy', 'id': 1357923}], 690: [{'name': 'fff', 'id': 19204023412}]}

res_list = row_splitter(data)

for key, val in res_list:
    print(f'{key} {val}')
```

**Output:**

```
12345 234564
12345 1357923
690 19204023412
```